# reactjs method not being called in render method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function to delete elements from an array in the state given its index. Here it is:

```
removeFromRowsById(index) {
    console.log("IN REMOVE FUNCTION");
    const newList = this.state.rows1;
    newList.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({ rows1: newList });
}
```

I call it in my render method like this:

```
this.removeFromRowsById.bind(this, this.state.rows1.indexOf(this.returnValueToDelete(this.state.rows1[1]["id"])))
```

The problem is, when I call it, nothing happens. It seems like it never goes in the method since "IN REMOVE FUNCTION" never gets logged in the console but `console.log(this.returnValueToDelete(this.state.rows1[index]["id"]))` does so I know that it's going in the if statement. Any type of help i highly appreciated it. I'm new to reactjs and I've been working on this for quite some time. Thanks!

Comment: I really don't know what the problem is, but you'll probably get more help - and perhaps even solve it yourself,if you refactor that `render` method a bit. I find inlining all that complex logic makes it really hard to read. (And I *like* 1-liners, within reason.)

Comment: calling a function that set the state inside the render my trap your component in an infinite loop...

Comment: @HamzaLH I understand but how else am I supposed to do it?

Comment: you should give us more code to understand the situation. maybe you can call the function in component did mount or when you are clicking on some button or maybe you should refactor all this in another component

Comment: @RobinZigmond I've updated the code. Please see how I call the method in my render function. Its a one liner

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the conditional?

```
!(columnToFilterOut.indexOf(rows1[index]["id"]) > -1)
```

It seems as though this condition will never be met, since you're unlikely to have a index that's Less than -1.

Comment: the condition is met whenever columnToFilterOut doesn't contain the element provided in the parameters. I tested this by printing the result

Comment: As per Zigmond's comment, I think you should refactor this a bit so that its more readable. Its a pretty heavily loaded one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I hope this will work for you

```
removeFromRowsById(index) {
    console.log("IN REMOVE FUNCTION");
    const newList = this.state.rows1;
    newList.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({ rows1: newList });
}
```

Call this function from render by this way:

```
this.removeFromRowsById(this.state.rows1.indexOf(this.returnValueToDelete(this.state.rows1[1]["id"])))
```